# Shell command to add a column to data (via another function)

Tags: shell, sh

I have data like

```
1234567890.123 'time1'
2345678901.234 'time2'
3456789012.345 'time3'
```

where the first number represents the epoch and I'd like to append a column with a human readable date. So something like `cut -c 1-10 | xargs -I {} date -r {}` is close but I'd like to keep around the other data on the line.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your data is just a string or something else, but if it is a string, you could just grep the first 10 numbers with grep and regex, convert to the readable date and append to the original string.

```
input="1234567890.123 'time1'"
readable="@$(echo $input| grep -oP '^[0-9]{10}')"
output="$input $(date -d $readable)"
```

I am using @ and -r for the conversion but this should work fine with the -r option too.

Comment: This isn't that different from the method in the question (uses `grep` instead of `cut`); what I am looking for is something I can pipe more easily but maybe the answer is just to write a custom function.

Comment: Can't you just append to the string of each line?

Comment: That's the question: `how to add a column to data`.